# NOT NULL constraint failed: products_order.user_id when trying to save serializer django rest frame work

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

django rest framework gives me this error when i am trying to perform a post request to create a new order even though i specified  the usr value in my serializer.save method.

here is my view

```
    class OrderListCreateAPI(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwner]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Order.objects.filter(user= user)
        
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        instance = serializer.save(user = self.request.user)
        order = Order.objects.get(id = instance['id'].value)
        order.item.quantity -= order.quantity
        order.save()
```

my models.py

```
    payment_methods = ((1,'credit card'),(2, 'cash'),(3, 'paypal'))

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/', height_field=300, width_field=300)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Order(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    payment_options = models.CharField(choices=payment_methods, max_length=50)
    Delivery = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

my serializers

```
    class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'description','image', 'price', 'quantity', 'seller', 'date']
        read_only_fields = ['date', 'seller']

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['user']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `perform_create` and not `perform_update` in your view.

```py
class OrderListCreateAPI(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwner]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Order.objects.filter(user= user)
        
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        instance = serializer.save(user = self.request.user)
        order = Order.objects.get(id = instance['id'].value)
        order.item.quantity -= order.quantity
        order.save()
```

Comment: perform create terminates after the serializer is saved